# A question about the polynomials $1+2x+\cdots+(2n+1) x^{2n}$, $n \in \mathbb Z_+$

Tags: calculus, limits

Are these known facts?

> For $n \in \mathbb Z_+$ set 
>   $$
> P_n(x) =  \sum_{k=0}^{2n} (k+1) x^k, \qquad x \in \mathbb R.
> $$
>
> 1. For every $n \in \mathbb Z_+$ there exists unique $x_n \in (-1,0)$ such that $P_n(x_n) \leq P_n(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R.$
> 2. For every $n \in \mathbb Z_+$ we have $P_n(x_n) \gt 1/4.$
> 3. $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = -1$.
> 4. $\lim_{n\to \infty} P_n(x_n) = 1/4$.

Comment: Every true statement is a consequence of well-known facts. How much reasoning you would need to get from well-known facts to the given statement is a completely different story. Also, in the title, don't you mean $1+2x+\cdots+(2n+1) x^{2n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$ P_n'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}k(k+1)x^{k-1}=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}\left[1-(n+1)(2n+1)x^{2n}+4n(n+1)x^{2n+1}-n(2n+1)x^{2n+2}\right] $$
so $P_n'(-1)=-2n(n+1)$ and $P_n(-1)=n+1$. Since:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left((1-x)^3 P_n'(x)\right)= 2n(2n+1)(2n+2)(1-x)^2 x^{2n-1} $$
it follows that $P_n(x)$ has an absolute minimum in the interval $(-1,0)$. Since:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}(k+1)x^k = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} $$
and the convergence is uniform over any compact subset of $(-1,0]$, every point is quite easy to prove.